# Android software architecture with Sqlite and REST WS

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, rest, architecture

I am actually developing applications on Android platform, and I need some help to have a good architecture.

I have some constraints :

- I have to use an SQLite DB when I dont have a network connection
- I have to use a REST WebService when I have a network connection

I actually develop my apps with these layers :

- Layout corresponding to the view
- Activity corresponding to the controller
- Service facade permitting to access my DAO or my REST client classes
- DTO corresponding to a simple model
- DAO / REST client classes to access my data

Activities contain only services and DTO.
Services contains only DAO / REST client classes and returns DTO.

I wanted to know what is the best way to manage data in an android app ? What is the most efficient architecture, and the cleanest one ?

Thanks you for your answers :-)

See you :D